# Login to .do website automatically (xcode)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to find a way to automatically login to this website by passing username and password into the URL, but I can't get it to work.

The URL is: https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/displayLogon.do

I've tried: https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/displayLogon.do?username=myUsername&password=secretPassword

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

I've tried this, but no luck:

```
NSString *Url = @"https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/logon.do";

    NSString *username = @"username";
    NSString *password = @"password";

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", username, password];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:Url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

---Update---
Here is where I'm at now, still can't login.

```
password = [password stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
username = [username stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
namePassword = [namePassword stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
nameUsername = [nameUsername stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/logon.do"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@&%@=%@", nameUsername, username, namePassword, password];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
self.connection = connection;

[connection start];
```

Comment: From the source: `<form name="logonForm" method="post" action="...">`. It requires a POST request.

Comment: How have you tried the POST request?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get POST request to work.

Comment: I seem to be able to post username only, not the password, so login always fails. How can I post both? e.g.     NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", username, password];

Comment: I think I've found the problem, it is when the field has a special character, e.g. password=Password100%  It doesn't like the % character and posts a blank password in the request. How can I get it to allow special characters when someone's password is secure?

Answer (score 0):

When communicating with an server on an website there are some options. To login you can use (as developer on the server) "POST" and "GET". What you are doing is the GET method. You can instantly know if this is the method to login by typing in some credentials and try to login. You will see the fields appear in the address bar (you don't even have to got the right credentials).

So most likely it will be POST. This way you send the credentials to the server by fields who are invisible at first or to "normal" user. There is some free stuff out there to see what name will be used when sending the POST request. You can hit f12 in firefox (will be something similar for other browsers) and see all the HTML. And you can indeed see that they use "password" and "username" for the field names (although this is not necessary!). You will have to POST your username and password to those fields to try to get it to work.

Based on your tags I assume that you want to make that happen in Xcode with objective-c or Swift. For objective-c you can search for "NSURLconnection" or the newer one "NSURLSession".

There is alot you can read, but to start this is good to read: http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/ .But you can try almost any tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you like to use GET and web service is designed to use POST method.
You can simply check web service is GET or POST by paste whole lines to web browser address bar.
Or you can use Chrome Extension Postman to check web service working correct and test parameters.

In my experience using SOAP, it was sending SOAP message as post body and your code seems like to be changed like below;

```
NSString *Url = @"https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/logon.do";

NSString *username = @"username";
NSString *password = @"password";

NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
    <soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope\"
    soap:encodingStyle=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding\">
    <soap:Body xmlns:m=\"http://www.example.org/logon.do\">
    <m:logon.do>
    <m:username>%@</m:username>
    <m:password>%@</m:password>
    </m:logon.do>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>", username, password];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:Url];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)         [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

That soap message template is not correct but you need to send whole soap message wrapping parameters, not just parameters.

Comment: How do you know the site supports SOAP requests?

Comment: I don't know it supports SOAP! I'm trying different things until it works, I'm learning and a newbie! Thanks for the tip re: Postman extension. Even using that I can't seem to get it to work though :(

Comment: To know whether it is working with SOAP, you need to contact web service developer and you can get from him/her about WSDL for each request.